# How to pass references to a class in C#/XNA/Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm making a 2D tower defense game in XNA and for my enemies I need to pass their starting coordinates into the Game1 class so I can draw them at the correct spot. However, since Game1 is a pre-made class I don't think I can pass in references for them. Is there any way to pass in variables via references without modifying the parameters (I think that's the stuff in the parentheses) for a class.
Just ask for clarification. THANK YOU!!!
(Ant is enemy and startplace is defined in a base class of ant)

P.S BUg.startplace does not work

Code:

```
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            background = Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");

            Texture2D AntTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ant");
//ant1 is already made I'm just setting it to something here
            ant1 = new Ant(AntTexture, Bug.startplace, 100, 10, 0.5f);
            Texture2D BlueberryBushTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("blueberrybush");
            player = new Player(level, BlueberryBushTexture);




            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }
```

Comment: Surely you're creating these objects in the `Game1` class? Your game won't draw anything until the rendering pipeline begins..

Comment: Yes I'm creating the class in Game1 but then to draw it in the correct spot (just to start off) I need to pass in the coords which are determined in the class.

Comment: Are they public properties of your enemy classes?

Comment: Yes, it's public, should I put it in the constructor though?

Comment: Show some code and explain what you're trying to do with it. I can keep guessing what your code looks like for hours.

Comment: Actually nevermind the startplace doesnt actually matter since the drawing is done later. I mixed up the draw and LoadContent() methods

Comment: I'm gonna answer my own question cause it was just a brain flop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized, the startplace variable doesn't actually matter since the drawing is done later. I mixed up the draw() and LoadContent() methods. Sorry for this brain flop!!!